# Understanding the bound given by Johnson–Lindenstrauss lemma

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, high-dimensional

This was a question I asked in the mathematics site. Though no one replied but I have figured it out. But new questions arise.

**Former Question:**

Here I choose to use the statement made by S.Dasgupta:

For any $0<\epsilon<1$ and any integer $n$, let $k$ be a positive integer s.t.
$$k \geq 4(\epsilon^2/2-\epsilon^3/3)^{-1} \ln n $$

Then for any set $V$ of $n$ points in $R^d$, there is a linear map $f: R^d \mapsto R^k$, such that for all $u,v \in V$,
$$ (1-\epsilon)\|u-v\|^2 \leq \|f(u)-f(v)\|^2 \leq (1+\epsilon)\|u-v\|^2$$

My question is, that I did some easy calculation to test the $k$ given by the lemma, for example, pick $n=2, \epsilon = 0.1$, and now we have $k \geq 595$ according to the lemma. But it is clear that in the 2-points case we can reduce the dimension to simply one. This makes me confused. Could anyone explain this?

**New Questions**

The answer to the question above, in my opinion, is the requirement to the map $f$. First, it must be a map from $R^D$ to $R^k$ but not $V$ to some $U \subset R^k$. Second, it is linear.

However, the requirement of **"linear map"** is seen on Wikipedia and in the book *Geometric Structure of High-Dimensional Data and Dimensionality Reduction*, but not in the original paper of S.Dasgupta. So the first question would be:**Is linear map required? And how to prove it?**

Besides, I found that $k$ is usually much greater than 2 or 3, which makes the visualization very difficult. I do not think it's ordinary. **Is it the daily case in DR?**